# How to force the removal of a windows service?

Tags: .net, windows-services

I created and installed a .NET Windows Service and now that I deleted its executable file I can't remove it from services.msc anymore with

```
InstallUtil.exe /u executablefilename.exe
```

How do I remove it?

Comment: command you type should remove service what error do you get?

Comment: do you try to refresh list? if command is executed without errors, you should refresh services list and the service will hide

Answer (score 13, accepted):

At the command line:

```
sc delete "service_name"
```

Answer (score 6):

You can try to do theses step in a command line:

```
>NET STOP YouServiceName
>InstallUtil.exe /u YouServiceName.exe
>sc delete YouServiceName
```

And, if all these doesn't work, try to kill the executable process with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd>.

Answer (score 2):

Try to install the executable again and then remove it.

OR: Delete it in your Registry

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services
```

and restart.

Comment: I won't mess with the registry.